# Remove/mark the seen posts on the Facebook news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, news-feed

I follow three Facebook pages and check their posts every morning on my news feed. The problem is I don't know what was the last post I saw the day before. Is there any way to remove all the seen posts or at least mark them as read?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove or mark as seen to a post on News Feed. But you can [hide a post](https://www.facebook.com/help/268028706671439) in your News Feed.

> To hide a post in your News Feed, click three dots (**...**) in the top right of the post and select the options:
>
> - **Hide post:** Hides a single post and gives you the option to see fewer posts from a specific person, Page or group.

Instead of hiding posts, it's better to [see posts on News Feed in most recent order](https://www.facebook.com/help/218728138156311?helpref=faq_content):

> > You can view posts by most recent, but News Feed will eventually return to its default setting.
>
> By default, News Feed shows the most popular posts first. To temporarily view stories by most recent:
>
> 1. Click **Home** at the top of Facebook.
> 2. Hover over the News Feed tab in the left side menu and click three dots(**...**).
> 3. Select **Most Recent**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: @Mori : You have to set it everytime whenever you refresh. As mentioned in answer _By default, News Feed shows the most popular posts first. You can view posts by most recent, but News Feed will eventually return to its default setting._ So, it is working as per it's behaviour. You cannot do much here.

Comment: I did set it to no success. So disppointing!